# How to split a 200 Amp main feed betweena cabin and workshop?

Tags: wiring

[image: 15' meter loop 200amp]
I currently have a meter loop on my cabin that feeds a 125a main breaker panel. I'm working with the the utility provider to move the meter to a pole ~75ft away from the cabin and run a new underground feed West to the cabin breaker panel. Additionally I need to run power to a workshop that is 55' to the South of the new pole location. The workshop will be a 70amp breaker box. (10a lights, 3@20a for tools). 
My question is how do I configure the split? Is there a main disconnect panel set up for split feeds from the meter that I can use instead of the standard as shown in the diagram? 
Also, I have to use 3 lengths of 2-0 in conduit for the cabin 125a feed, what gauge works for the 70a workshop?

Comment: It's allowed to oversubscribe breakers... They don't need to add up.  What appliances will you ultimately use in the shop?

Comment: How many square feet is the shop? Also, are you using metal or nonmetallic conduit for the conduit runs underground?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually install two main disconnects below the meter. The NEC allows up to six main disconnects at one location so long as they are all marked as SERVICE DISCONNECT. These labels usually come with the equipment.

There are several ways you can do this but I have found the simplest to install an MLO (Main Lug Only) panel and then install the breakers to each building. The only qualifier is that you cannot have any more spaces than would allow more than six mains (6-2 pole breakers would equal 12 spaces or poles). If you have a problem finding a panel to match that configuration Then just instal a 125A MCB panel install the breakers to each building below the main.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Wouldn’t OP want 200 amp panel (not 125)?  Doesn’t that then invalidate his assertion that he needs three 2-0’s is wrong because he also needs ground?  And he’ll likely need to split the neutrals and grounds up in the current panel?

Comment: There is no problem with upgrading to a 200A MCB, but we really don't know what the demand is since we don't have enough information to calculate total demand. Also and this might be me overlooking who we are dealing with, but the industry usually refers to circuits as a 3 wire with ground. I am assuming that since @Robert Clyburn took the time to scan a riser and try and detail his intent, he does have some technical help or experience. Since he is installing a new service it must be permitted and the AHJ will make sure he has all code bases covered before passing the installation.

Comment: 200 amp is hidden in the question title.  The diagram posted is identical (except the logo in the lower right corner) to one printed as example in my own utilities planning booklet.  It’s true that there is no load/demand data available in the question for the “shop” other than OP’s assertion of “70 amp”.  This question is a good example of where my personal limit gets reached-I know what needs to happen but if I try and answer I’ll leave another important point out.

Comment: You are correct. Unfortunately our answers are limited to the scope of the question and any edits. Otherwise we are moving into discussion and off topic.

Comment: The shop load is minimal, we planned a 10amp for the lights, and 3 20amps for 2 interior 110v loops with one exterior. No constant or heavy draws are expected: just table saw compressor etc.

Comment: @RobertClyburn are you aware that there needs to be 4 conductors total from the pole to each building? And that this change likely means neutrals and grounds must be separate in the existing panel in the cabin?  (They might be now, but more likely are not)