# RV sub panel on main feed

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I want to add an RV subpanel to our cabin, but the location where I want it is very close to the main service switch, but pretty far from the circuit panel inside the cabin. Currently, there is about 100' of underground wire (I think it's MCM 250 aluminum) feeding into the cabin. What I want to do is put in a subpanel, but connect it to the main supply feed (but after the service disconnect switch).

I was thinking that I could use a tap to pull a 6ga wire off of the MCM 250 inside the service disconnect and run that (through underground conduit) to the RV sub panel. I'm having trouble finding out if that is legal though. I was going to put a 4x4 pressure treated post in the ground and mount the sub panel to that, and run the 6ga wire underground through the conduit to it.

Here's a picture of what I have in mind:

[image: Wiring Diagram]

You can ignore the generator part of the diagram for now, unless you want to comment on what I have in mind (putting the ATS right below the service switch about 20-25' from the generator).

Is what I have in mind here kosher? Or do I need another main cutoff switch before the RV sub panel?

One of the main questions I have is if I can tap on the switched (after the main 200a breaker) side of the main service switch using something like a "Morris 97643 Multi-Cable Connector", then run the tapped wire off to a sub panel. Since the main service switch would switch off both the circuit breaker in the cabin as well as the sub panel, I'm wondering if that is ok.

Comment: Where is the meter located? If it's next to your 200A panel you probably won't have much choice in that regard

Comment: It's right above the 'main service switch' in my diagram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a 200 Amp main feed betweena cabin and workshop?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136801/how-to-split-a-200-amp-main-feed-betweena-cabin-and-workshop)

Comment: I updated the question to clarify what I think is different.

Comment: You may want to change,the 200 amp main breaker panel. To a WP 2oo amp panel with room to feed house sub panel , and rv hook up and a couple of spares.  It may look neater,not sure on how much room you have were your service comes in.  Your  200 amp main looks  like not much room for tapping into..

Comment: It's actually pretty big. The picture is not the actual panel, just an example for a diagram. But assuming I do upgrade if needed, can I tap into the bottom/switched side, or do I need to feed 2 disconnect switches coming from the meter?

Comment: Is the under ground from the pole run in pvc  conduit or metal?  Im asking in case a pull box is need to do your tap if you choose that route. you could  come. off the 200 main  close nipple to pull box do your taps off the load side of the breaker all taps would be in large enough pull box. To your RV location.

Comment: Yes there are codes on how long taps may be.And yours seems to be to long .With out a breaker close to taps. Then off to RV hook up.

Comment: Yes you can tap into wire.The points im making are you may have to add a pull box for splice .  And add a panel for the RV in that location done that way .  Wall will have more stuff on it and not look good .  Where you change the disconnect,it maybe neater .And not look like a after thought.

Comment: There is a 25’ tap rule look at section 240.21. The tap would have to be sized at a minimum of 1/3 the feeder and terminate in a breaker, not a problem there usually conduit or a gutter is also required. I have installed many RV power pedestals that have 50a 240 breakers but also have 30 a 120 and 20a 120 outlets in 1 box designed for just this case they run ~ 120$ with some close to 200$ So it can be done (just like the one in your picture), the question is how to make the tap. That depends on the disconnect some have multiple lugs, some times a 3 point Polaris connector is the way to go.

Comment: Can you post an actual photo of the main service switch on the pole?

Comment: Also, I would look very strongly at setting it up so that the generator only powers a dedicated set of standby loads, instead of trying to transfer the entire cabin....

Comment: Is it legal to add Polaris connector for splice in the panel box ? Or do you have to add a pull box?    That is my concern  and is AHJ going to have a problem with that.

Comment: 25 foot tap rule is fine if the RV hook up is 25 feet away.If more than that it needs a breaker..Side of the house may have added pull box and a breaker box for RV.  Were as you change your 200 amp main to have room for the RV and a spare ,all in one box.

Comment: How far from the tap is the RV hook up going to be clears up a lot of  things?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, I'll get a picture when I'm there in a few days. As far as the generator goes, I've gone back and forth on that one. It's a lot simpler to put it near the pole like in my picture. The generator I'm getting has a demand control system that you can use to switch off breakers inside if needed. But the total load of the cabin is well under the capacity of the gen. There is no AC and heat is geothermal, so we just need to power the pump to keep from freezing. I can put the RV panel within a 25' run, that's pretty close to where I wanted it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can tap into the conductors in the cabinet.  As long as it meets...Chapter 3,  Article 312  cabinets and cutout boxes. ( Installation 312.8 )  Over current enclosures taps,and feed through conductors 75% fill. And taps may run up to 25 feet..240.21  wire is a least 1/3 the size of the conductor. your tapping into